# Is this explanation of the workings of a rheostat consistent with the diagram?

Tags: rheostat

I came across this description of a rheostat along with a diagram:

[image]

> ...The best example is the traditional dial controlling volume on a radio. The outer ring, or toroid coil, consists of a resistive wire wrapped in a spiral about a ring of insulating material. Electricity must travel along a sliding wiper and through the coil before itleaves the resistor. When the knob is turned *clockwise*, the electricity has *less* wire to travel through so that the resulting current is stronger and the volume is louder.

Won't turning the knob clockwise *increase* the distance between input and output, causing the electricity to have to travel through more resistive wire, thus increasing resistance, decreasing amperage and consequently, volume?

Comment: A volume control is invariably a potentiometer, not a rheostat. Connect signal to the "not used" terminal and ground to the"current in" terminal. Now you get the right variable voltage from the wiper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are correct, the drawing appears to be mirrored. However, note that wire wound pots are rarely used these days. Instead carbon or conductive plastic [potentiometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) are typical, which use the same principal. Wire wound pots are usually often used when high current/power rating or low resistance is needed.

Comment: Thanks but was aware of that. Was getting a refresher, this jumped out, so wanted to double check that I wasn't rusty to the point of missing something obvious.

Comment: Rheostats are still used on "100V line" PA (public-address) systems. I'm standing beside one right now. The rheostat is simply wired in series with the loudspeaker transformer (which usually has multiple power tap-off points on the secondary). It's not hi-fi but it works.

Comment: @Transistor that's true! (back in the 90's I designed such a system with well over 1000 panels.) They can sound pretty good with decent speakers and transformers. It's a fairly specialist application though.

Comment: The difference between a rheostat and a potentiometer is that the rheostat is a two terminal variable resistance (controls current) whereas a potentiometer is a three terminal device which varies the voltage (potential) at the centre terminal.

Comment: @IanBland - you are correct, thank you. Will correct.

Comment: Cermet pots are also common. Good for low resistance and low inductance, unlike wirewound. Usually see them as multi-turn pots.